# Adding Security to .NET Web API

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, xamarin.forms

To put it simply, what is a proper way to implement security for an ASP.NET Web API site that will be interfacing with a mobile app (Android/iOS/WinPhone via Xamarin.Forms) and a website (unknown as to what that's written in, at this instant)? The Web API will feature just read/SELECT methods at the start, though in the future it'll most likely have a couple write/INSERT methods too.

I've used OAuth a little bit on a work side-project; is this sufficient to secure the Web API site? If so, could someone break down generally, and simply, what steps I should take to implement it?

By the way, the Web API will connect to an existing database and there should be no issue with adding several new tables for security (I'm assuming that'll be required).

I think that's all the relevant info I can think of. Thank you very much for any assistance. I'm not very strong in security, unfortunately, as my work projects haven't really been public facing like this will be.

Comment: If I were doing this today, I would use thinktecture identityserver with identity reboot. The original way was a little cumbersome.  The tutorials present the steps in a well thought out fashion and the sample projects will let you know if it meets your needs. https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/

Comment: Definitely identityserver is the way to go, however this article helped http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ in understanding the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at Thinktecture IdentityServer3.

It is ideal for what your aiming to do.

You basically need an endpoint that all clients (Your different apps) can request an access token from to then talk with your web api.

The beauty of IdentityServer3 is that you can configure each client application individually to talk to the Token Server.

I'm not going to lie, i found it quite the learning curve at first but it was well worth it.

If you have access to pluralsight, there's a great course on there that takes you through OpenId & Access token security, and implements it with IdentityServer3.

There are also alot of videos out there of either Brock Allen or Dominic Baier, walking you through the there IdentityServer3 middleware.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Looks like IdentityServer3 is the way to go for what I'm looking for. Do you know if it's easy to host? The client I am doing the Web API and mobile app for has an ASP website hosted by IIS; do you think that can host this (I know IIS can host Web API) IdentSvr3?

Comment: Very easy to host, its middleware, you can host it in IIS fine. You need to start the journey of learning this stuff, you will get a clear idea of what you need to do.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your answer Derek. I've started researching IS3 and it looks like it'll be great; I just have to learn it all first!